# Which tools can I use to benchmark a scala code?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, jvm, benchmarking

I'm doing a project where I need to analyze the differences between functional programming and imperative programming. I'm using Scala since it's a multi-paradigm language, for a fair comparison. 
Using languages that have a front-end on gcc, pin and perf(hardware) are suitable tools to do these comparisons, but now on Scala, I'm not finding substitutes.

I'm not interested on microbenchmark that only observe the time it took to run the algorithm. Since it's a conway's game of life implementation, a number of memory access is required and so on. I'm grateful for any help

Comment: First, this if completely off-topic. But, anyways, take a look to [**ScalaMeter**](https://scalameter.github.io/) & [**YourKit**](https://www.yourkit.com).

Comment: *Java Microbenchmark Harness* also works for Scala.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend [`ScalaMeter`](https://scalameter.github.io/). It is a *microbenchmarking* tool, but it does what you want by running the code multiple times, and removing the effects of *JIT* compiler warm-up, *garbage collection*, etc. It can also be configured to report memory usage, etc.

Comment: Ill remove the comments, I cant explain why I started this "war"... And yes  I really like JMH :)